# Getting a value from a command prompt command using python

Tags: python, scripting, command-prompt

```
import sys, os
X = os.system("ipconfig")
print X
0
```

I know its simple, I'm just starting python. How would I get X to equal the text that is printed out when I use `ipconfig` in a normal windows command prompt?

Comment: Using windows?  If your using freebsd/linux, I'd consider using file redirection and bypassing the extra python script completely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're looking for [`subprocess.check_output()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).

Comment: That's the one! Thanks friend

Answer (score 1):

Use [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html): `subprocess.checkoutput()` or `subprocess.Popen()`